# Resampling DataFrame in days but retaining original datetime index format

Tags: python, pandas

I have tick data that I would like to refine by removing the first and last rows of each day. The original dataframe has a datetime64[ns] index with a format of `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

To do so I used

```
pd.resample('D').first()
pd.resample('D').last()
```

and successfully sampled out the first and last rows of each day
The problem is when resampling in days the original datetime index transforms into a '%Y-%m-%d' format

How do I use resample so that it retains the original datetime index format?
or is there a way I can reformat datetime index in the new dataframe to display until seconds?

Comment: Yes I understand. The issue is that the original datetime index has time but when resampling by days the time of the indices become all 0. The pandas documentation says the original index format should be retained but to be it seems they don't.

Comment: So you want the zeros back?

Comment: I want the original time data back

Comment: Resample by day will set time to `00:00:00` which is the beginning of the day. Similarly, resample by month will set day and time to `01 00:00:00` which is the beginning of the month.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### IIUC

Your problem is that you are resampling daily and getting the first value per day.  But that you want to include the associated date for that first value.

You want to aggregate the date in your index as well.

```
df.assign(NewDate=df.index).resample('D').first().set_index('NewDate')
```

Or you can `resample` the index and grab min values

```
df.loc[df.index.to_series().resample('D').min()]
```